# How to pin application into taskbar programmatically

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I have tried this code it works fine for unpinning application from taskbar in Windows 10 but it is not working for pinning application into taskbar.

```
public static void PinUnpinTaskbar(bool pin)
{
    string l_strFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
    if (!File.Exists(l_strFilePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException(l_strFilePath);
    int MAX_PATH = 255;
    var actionIndex = pin ? 5386 : 5387; // 5386 is the DLL index for"Pin to Tas&kbar", ref. http://www.win7dll.info/shell32_dll.html
                                         //uncomment the following line to pin to start instead
                                         //actionIndex = pin ? 51201 : 51394;
    StringBuilder szPinToStartLocalized = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
    IntPtr hShell32 = LoadLibrary("Shell32.dll");
    LoadString(hShell32, (uint)actionIndex, szPinToStartLocalized, MAX_PATH);
    string localizedVerb = szPinToStartLocalized.ToString();

    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(l_strFilePath);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(l_strFilePath);

    // create the shell application object
    dynamic shellApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));
    dynamic directory = shellApplication.NameSpace(path);
    dynamic link = directory.ParseName(fileName);

    dynamic verbs = link.Verbs();
    for (int i = 0; i < verbs.Count(); i++)
    {
        dynamic verb = verbs.Item(i);
        if (verb.Name.Equals(localizedVerb))
        {
            verb.DoIt();
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot see anything wrong in your solution, also tried it several times but the verb does no longer exist. After some research I found this:

[Update KB3093266 removes shell.Application object 'taskbarpin' verb](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/12bd7a43-bbe0-4a69-ad37-f724fbdccd30/update-kb3093266-removes-shellapplication-object-taskbarpin-verb?forum=win10itprogeneral)

> Update KB3093266 removes shell.Application object 'taskbarpin' verb
>   for adding taskbar pin item pins
>
> It is most likely broken by one of the updates that KB3093266
>   supersedes

And this (Powershell but same library): [Pin to Taskbar fails in Windows 10](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7880f228-8491-4005-a82c-152510d8ba03/powershell-pin-to-taskbar-fails-in-windows-10?forum=winserverpowershell)